Does Grails 6 no longer support profiles
Does Grails 6 no longer support creating profiles? I downloaded grails cli 6.0.0 and 6.2.0. When running
$ grails create-profile exampleProject the command is not recognized. It is also not listed in the list of commands under $ grails --help
That is odd because the official documentation shows it as a command in version 6.0. What is supposed to replace profiles if they are no longer supported?
https://docs.grails.org/6.0.0/guide/profiles.html
Tried downloading grails cli versions 6.0.0 and 6.2.0.

Yes, Grails framework 6 introduced a new Grails Forge CLI. It has the concept of multiple ApplicationType to meet your specific needs.
Currently it offer support for WEB, REST-API, Web-Plugin, Plugin. One can extend the Grails Forge or send a PR to support additional application types.
Here is the blog post where we've introduced the new Grails Forge - a lightening fast CLI for Grails Application Generation
The Grails Documentation seems outdated in terms of Grails Profiles which need to be removed from the documentation. Also, I'd suggest to browse the latest documentation.
